# What's gonna happen if a nuclear bomb explodes nearby?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, explosions

I live in the capital, 10 km from its center on the 9th floor, my windows facing the opposite direction will I still see a flash? Will I hear something? How loud will it be? How fast would I die? If I survive the blast what should do? Should I go underground or climb higher?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_nuclear_explosions)

Comment: I think somebody survived Hiroshima's explosion, 300m from its center.

Comment: It's high time to [stop worrying and love the Bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr_strangelove)! You implicitly assume that only the center of your city would be targeted; this may not be the case. Would suggest reading Glasstone, Dolan, the Effects of Nuclear Weapons for much more grisly (but still usable) information than can fit into the remaining 245 characters...

Comment: This is a [nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTdy1Yp1h5A).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gugg's article is far enough as it covers everything you require. Firstly, It depends on the bomb. In other words, it's based on *how bad the bomb is*.

This [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon#Fission_weapons) quotes it...

> The amount of energy released by fission bombs can range from the equivalent of just under a ton of TNT, to upwards of 500,000 tons of TNT.

If that bomb is similar to Hiroshima's (equivalent to 20k tons of TNT), then [here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aAbombdamage1945.svg) how the effect of the bomb would be. 10 km would be *"out"* of this scale and hence, you'd experience *nothing*...

---

> My windows facing the opposite direction, will I still see a flash?

I think you didn't *correctly* define this. At its present form, this is somewhat ridiculous to ask. But, from your region - it's quite a fireworks to see...

> Will I hear something? How loud will it be?

No. All those pressure waves would lose energy and probably diminish off before reaching you. I think there won't be any harmful effects like doors & windows "banging". etc...

> How fast would I die? If I survive the blast what should do? Should I go underground or climb higher?

Why should you do something when nothing happens to you? *You wouldn't die*..! Better take a vacation and stay off from the region.

Comment: Of course, this answer assumes the bomb would be like Hiroshima's, which might easily not be the case…

Comment: Sure but with this kind of reasoning it might as well be a constipated unicorn... An example and equivalency in TNT was given, if you expect a larger device redo the maths with it in mind...